# Inconsistent behavior in .click() function in cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, ag-grid

I have an edit box would like to click and then type in value.

So, my code is

```js
cy.get('.ag-row-last > [aria-colindex="3"] ').click().type('65{enter}')
```

The problem is 50% time, it can open that edit box like below image and then I can type in value

[image]

However, 50% time. I get failure. it cannot open it up as below image

[image]

therefore, it gives me this error

> cy.type() failed because it requires a valid typeable element.
>
> The element typed into was:
>
> ```html
> <div class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-normal-height is-editable 
>    ccr-cell-with-icon ccr-numeric-input right-border 
>    ag-right-aligned-cell ag-cell-focus ag-cell-value" 
>    unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-colindex="3" 
>    role="gridcell" col-id="weight" style="left: 562.5px; width: 120px;">
> </div>
> ```
>
> A typeable element matches one of the following selectors.....

I understand this error because the input was not found because the edit box was closed.

How could I get rid of this inconsistency issue?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, inconsistent behaviour can be fixed by adding a "guard" check between actions (i.e the `.click()` and the `.type()` commands).

For example, see the `ag-cell-not-inline-editing` class, this changes to `ag-cell-inline-editing` after the click, so you could try

```js
cy.get('.ag-row-last > [aria-colindex="3"] ')
  .should('have.class', 'ag-cell-not-inline-editing')
  .click()
  .should('have.class', 'ag-cell-inline-editing')      // wait for cell state change
  .type('65{enter}')
```

There are other changes after the click, for example the following block of HTML is added to the grid cell

```html
<div class="ag-cell-edit-wrapper">
  <!--AG-INPUT-TEXT-FIELD-->
  <div
    role="presentation"
    class="ag-cell-editor ag-labeled ag-label-align-left ag-text-field ag-input-field"
    ref="eInput"
  >
    <div
      ref="eLabel"
      class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-text-field-label"
      aria-hidden="true"
      role="presentation"
    ></div>
    <div
      ref="eWrapper"
      class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-text-field-input-wrapper"
      role="presentation"
    >
      <input
        ref="eInput"
        class="ag-input-field-input ag-text-field-input"
        type="text"
        id="ag-895-input"
        aria-label="Input Editor"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so you might use this in the test

```js
cy.get('.ag-row-last > [aria-colindex="3"] ')
  .should('have.class', 'ag-cell-not-inline-editing')
  .click()
  .find('input.ag-input-field-input')               // waits for the input to appear
  .type('65{enter}')
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, may i ask about what u mean "wait for cell state change" here

Comment: May I ask that the guard you mean is to prevent the next action to trigger too quickly right? 
Right now, it seems that the edit box was closed after opening up, but not doing the .type() before .click() . 
Coz the original value in edit box was cleared after .click() in the failed time. If the failure is because of doing the .type() too fast, then I think the original value should be still here